# Taylor Polynomials

Tags: calculus

Find the Taylor polynomial $T_5(x)$ = of order 5 about $x = 0$ for $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$. Write down the remainder term $R_5(x)$ and estimate the size of the error if $T_5(1)$ is used as an approximation to $f(1)$.

My attempt at the question:
I think this is the correct Taylor polynomial:
$$T_5(x) = 1 + \frac{x}2 - \frac{x^2}8 + \frac{x^3}{12} - \frac{5x^4}{128}+\frac{7x^5}{256}$$
I'm not sure if this fully answers the remainder term part:
$$R_5(x) = \frac{f^{(6)}(c)}{6!}x^6$$

Could someone please give some pointers on how to estimate the size of the error and just check if the other parts are correct. Thank you for any help.

Comment: FAQ section + Reading directions to use LaTeX to write mathematicas + using those directions in posts here = nice looking and appealing questions.

Comment: You should specify if you need the Peano (little-o reminder) or the Lagrange reminder, which is exactly the one you wrote, only with $c \in [o,x]$.

Comment: @Cornelis sorry I forgot to specify. I meant to specify Lagrange remainder

Answer (score 3):

Recall that
$$(1+x)^\alpha=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}x^k+o(x^n)$$
so take $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ and try to simplify $\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}$ with this value.

Now for the remainder: by [Taylor-Lagrange formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) there's $\xi \in (0,x)$
$$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$
so if there's $M>0 $ s.t. 
$$|f^{(n+1)}(y)|\leq M \quad \forall y\in[0,x]$$
then we have an estimate for the error:
$$|R_n(x)|\leq\frac{M}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$

Comment: You're welcome.